# prototype confusion: parent prototype property affected by child prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm reading a book on OOP javascript and got stuck on one of the examples.

In the first version of the sample code, a new instance of the `Shape` constructor function is created and the `toString` method is called. The `toString` method returns "Triangle" which is the `name` property of the `Triangle` prototype, even though "Shape" is supposed to be the `name` property of the `Shape` prototype.

In the second version of the sample code, the `toString` method returns "Shape" as intended.
I'm wondering how the changes in the second version of the code made any difference because it seems like in both versions of the sample code, the `Triangle` prototype holds a reference to the `Shape` prototype so the `name` property of the `Shape` prototype would still be updated to "Triangle" because of `Triangle.prototype.name = "Triangle";`

first version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg9mS/)

second version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6H8U/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example,when you assigned `Triangle.prototype = new F();` then a new instance of `F function` has been created and it inherited prototype of `Shape` which means any changes in `Triangle.prototype` will be reflected in that object instance but not in the `F's constructor`, because an object instance can't change it's constructor but if you change in the `constructor's prototype/Shape.prototype` then any object that created by that constructor function will be reflected too. But if you were assigned `Triangle.prototype = F.prototype` it could be different.

I've made some changes [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6H8U/1/). Hope it'll help you to understand, see in the console.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, Triangle.prototype gets a new reference -- new F().  So, unlike in the first example, Triangle.prototype is actually a different reference than Shape.prototype.

Comment: If F() references Shape.prototype and Triangle.prototype references F(), doesn't Triangle.prototype reference Shape.prototype by the transitive property?

Comment: new F() and F.prototype is different.